# What is the state of the relationship between the US Democrats and Israel?

Tags: united-states, israel, iran

Recently, the Democrats granted a visa to Iran's President Raisi, against opposition, and he attacked the Holocaust. As I heard, some of his bodies who got visas are IRGC commanders, which is a terrorist organization according to American laws.

This begs the question, why should they be given visas?

What is the state of the relationship between the US Democrats and Israel?

Comment: please provide some links to your sources in the future, rather than forcing us to research your claims: *As I heard,*...

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a smidgen more transparency would benefit this question?  Who is issuing the visa, and for what purpose?

From [State Department](https://www.voanews.com/a/us-facing-pressure-to-deny-iran-s-president-visa-for-un-visit-/6717453.html), not "the Democrats".

> The State Department on Thursday indicated it would not deny a visa for the Iranians planning to attend the 77th session of the U.N. General Assembly in mid-September.
>
> "Visa records are confidential under U.S. law; therefore, I can't discuss the details of individual visa cases. But I would reiterate what we've said before: that **as a host nation of the U.N., the U.S. is generally obligated under the U.N. Headquarters Agreement to issue visas to representatives of U.N. member states to travel to the U.N. headquarters district,"** State Department deputy spokesperson Vedant Patel said in response to a question from VOA News.